# Know if a processus still running with his command line, in python

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have the command of a processus, and i want know if it still running with python.

[image]

I have the command line "java -Xms2000M ... nogui"

it's a sub process of a cmd windows.

the problem is: i don't know how to do that,
I read something about subprocess module and popen, but If someone would like to enlighten me

thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [wmic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic) to query all running Windows processes, wrapping that in a subprocess call and filter all processes by your needs (`java.exe`, `spigot-`):

```
import subprocess

def isProcessRunning(appName, argPattern):
    command = 'wmic process get Caption,Processid,Commandline /format:csv'
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
    stdout, stderr = cmd.communicate()
    if cmd.returncode == 0:
        for line in stdout.decode('utf-8').split('\n'):
            line = line.lower().strip()
            
            if not line:
                continue

            if appName in line and argPattern in line:
                print("Found:")
                print(line)
                return True

print(isProcessRunning('spotify.exe', 'renderer'))
```

Out:

```
Found:
vm-pc_win7,spotify.exe,"c:\users\f3k\appdata\roaming\spotify\spotify.exe" --type=renderer ... --product-version=spotify/1.1.43.700 --disable-spell-checking --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=1 --renderer-client-id=4 --mojo-platform-channel-handle=2268 /prefetch:1,5148
True
```

**Note:**
wmic returns a CSV format, I am just going to search the whole string.